# C# SDK posting to my own Page feed

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, oauth-2.0

The situation:
I have a website and creates "posts". As a new post is created I want to send the new post to my facebook pages feed. I have all of the code down to do this and it works fine as long as I get an access token from the graph API explorer tool. This is not going to work as it expires after about an hour. When I generate the access token from code, it appears that it is a app access token and it does not give me access to my page. So the big question is how do I obtain a user access token from code that will have access to post to my page.

Here is how I am getting the access token.

```
 private static string GetApiAccessToken()
    {
        var client = new FacebookClient();
        dynamic result = client.Get("oauth/access_token", new
        {
            client_id = SessionGetter.Instance.FacebookApiKey,
            client_secret = SessionGetter.Instance.FacebookSecretKey,
            grant_type = "client_credentials",
            scope = "manage_pages"
        });

        return result.access_token;
    }
```

Then I use the access token to try and get the Page access token and this is where it tells me that I don't have authorization and all I get back in the dictionary is an "id".

```
private static string GetPageAccessToken(string accessToken, string pageId)
    {
        try
        {
            var fb = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

            var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();

            parameters["fields"] = "access_token";
            var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)fb.Get(pageId, parameters);

            var pageAccessToken = (string)result["access_token"];

            return pageAccessToken;
        }
        catch (FacebookApiException ex)
        {
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Now like I said, if I use the access token from the graph explorer, the code works fine.
Then the post is made to the graph API

```
 var facebookClient = new FacebookClient(pageAccessToken);
            var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)facebookClient.Post("me/feed", new Dictionary<string, object>
{{"message",postMessage},                                                                              {"picture", csLogo},
{"link", LinkHelper.AssignmentUrl(wrapper.Assignment)}});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user access token has `manage_pages` extended permissions.

then make a request to `me/accounts` to the get the page access token.

Then post to `{pageid}/feed` using the **page** access token.